# Alphabetize multi-dimensional array using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If i have an array:

```
myArray = [['0','Mouse'],['1','Dog'],['2','Cat'],['3','Gerbil']];
```

How can I alphabetize the array based on the, in this case, animals?

```
myArray = alpha(myArray);
```

Results:

```
myArray = [['2','Cat'],['1','Dog'],['3','Gerbil'],['0','Mouse']];
```

Comment: you mean to sort, or what does *alphabetize* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The **`sort()`** method sorts the elements of an array *in place* and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

in combination with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

> The **`localeCompare()`** method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

```js
var array = [['5', 'Mouse'], ['0', 'Mouse'], ['1', 'Dog'], ['2', 'Cat'], ['3', 'Gerbil']];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How does it know to sort on the 'Mouse','Dog' index? Also, what would this look like on a one-dimensional array?

Comment: do you see `[1]`? it uses the index for the inner arrays.

Comment: i see the [1], but why isn't it something like [i][1] since it's a multi-dimension array?

Comment: the sort method uses the items of the array and checks two elements and then the function takes fom an element the item with index `1` and from the other item the other value with index `1` and returns a value from `localCompare`. please have a look to the first given link in my answer.

Comment: so if it was a single dimension array, would it be the same exact code?

Comment: yes, without using the index.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sort` function

```js
var myArray = [['0','Mouse'],['1','Dog'],['2','Cat'],['3','Gerbil']];
console.log(alpha(myArray));

var arr2 = [['5','Mouse'],['0','Mouse'],['1','Dog'],['2','Cat'],['3','G‌​erbil']];
console.log('another array', alpha(arr2));

function alpha(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1]);
}
```

Comment: sort works in place, your return suggest, you get a new array.

Comment: I am sorry @NinaScholz, did not understand your point, please explain..

Comment: your sort does not work with for example: `var myArray = [['5','Mouse'],['0','Mouse'],['1','Dog'],['2','Cat'],['3','Gerbil']];`, because of the wrong return value of the sort function.

Comment: I added mentioned by you array to my answer and see no problem there, oh, you probably mean non-latin, non-ascii chars..., I think it will work, but should be tested....

Comment: you may have a look to my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41493346/1447675

Comment: ok, thanks @Nina for pointing to this

Comment: Tried the sort and it works for the most part, but for some reason the first item on my list of 90 or so items starts with a "W". Somethings off :(

Comment: Try String#localeCompare proposed by @NinaScholz

Comment: just to add my liked commet (of the now deleted answer): it depends on the implementation of sort by the vendor. your callback returns only two values instead of three, because less than zero values are missing. this leads to fancy values in certain user agents, like edge. you could minimize this behaviour if you take the whole possible spectrum of return values of less than zero, zero or greater than zero values.